# Crontab for receiving udp messages in php

Tags: php, udp, cron

I am trying to accept a udp message and insert it into the database in php. i am doing it in server.php. i want server.php to run in the background and i am doing it through crontab. the entry for the crontab is */1 * * * * /Applications/bin/php5/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Path/server.php. My question is that it works fine when the I run it for first time but when I restart the MAMP (apache/php/MySQL servers) it does not work. Here is the code for server.php

```
<?php
include('db_connection.php');

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket,$ip_address,$port);

while(1)
{
  $IP = '';
  $PORT = 0;

  socket_recvfrom($socket,$buffer,1024,0,$IP,$PORT);
  $query = "INSERT INTO message_table VALUES ('$buffer', '$IP' , '$PORT')";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Insertion failed" . mysql_error());
}
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I am using MAC OSX 10.6
How can I do that or is there any approach to do this.
Any help will be appritiated.